# Google Maps JavaScript API の使用制限

Tags: google-maps

制限が25,000回と2,500回になる違いは何ですか？

Answer (score 0):

標準APIとAPIサービスの差です。
Google Maps APIの [ガイド](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage?hl=ja)に詳細が載っています。